# Create Excel file and save as PDF.

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I have an Xlsx file that I want to open, populate it with data from back-end and then save it as PDF on the client. The process would create about a 100 files at a time.

I searched around the web and realize that it is not possible to use Excel Interop any more. Do I have to use XML SDK?

I cannot use any third-party products or APIs. It is either using Interop or XML but just looking for coding suggestions. I do have Adobe pro license and have used in Office Automation to save Excel files as PDF.

What are my options? Any recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

What do you mean with: "it is not possible to use Excel Interop any more"?

[Office 2013 still have Interop library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320445.aspx) and it works perfectly fine under .NET 4.5.1
Just add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly to your references and you are ready to go.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace officeInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open("d:\\x.xlsx");
            wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "d:\\x.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MSFT thinks that using Interop in a web app is license violation, since the excel file is transmitted to the client.

Comment: NOTE: ExportAsFixedFormat only works if a default printer exists.

Comment: Used the library from SpireXLS to save as pdf. works quite well.

Comment: @user3150378 except Spire is expensive to someone.

Comment: Will office 2013 interope libraries work with office 2019?

Comment: @Addy Maybe. To be safe you'll need to compile on machine with 2019 Office installed against its interop libs. Be sure to check up-to-date instruction on Interop, my knowledge of it is from dark ages of 2010, I see that since 2016 there are Nuget packages so be sure to check new articles :)
Oh, and remember to Close interop Application, or you'll end up with bunch of orphaned office processes.

Comment: @PTwr: Just checked on Nuget, the latest available version is 15.0.4759 last published in September 2016. And yes you are right about closing the app I faced this issue back in 2016 while developing this app it was truly a nightmare and took me some time to figure out :)