# C# ASP.Net making pdf file

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

i need to create pdf file from my data. I already have excel .xlsx generated file in my code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcelFile()
{
    var result = GenerateExcelFile();
    return File(result, "application/ms-excel", "myFile.xlsx");
}

public byte[] GenerateExcelFile()
{
    byte[] output;
    var file = new ExcelPackage();
    // creating cells, adding text, some pictures and so on;
    output = file.GetAsByteArray();
    return output;
}
```

Is there any way to reuse my .xlsx generating code to create .pdf file without any additional libraries ? Do i have to use any third party libraries and generate my .pdf from zero?

Comment: It's technically *possible* to create a PDF file without using a PDF generating library.  But it's going to be pretty difficult.  You'll need to learn about the PDF file format standards and manually build the byte stream of the file.  It seems kind of unnecessary to do all that work when there exist plenty of libraries which already do it.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Excel Interop you can save as pdf. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874412/create-excel-file-and-save-as-pdf)

Comment: Interop is not an option, because there is no ms office. Is there any good free libraries, that can convert xlsx to pdf ?