# Generating PDF file from the output of a transformation in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl

I want to generate a PDF file with the output of a query in SSIS . The PDF file needs to have headers in one column and corresponding values in the other column.
Could someone please let me know if its possible to write a script which does that for any number of columns input to that script and can generate a PDF for each record corresponding to that input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why “is it possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: @sqluser check my answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one direct way to create pdf report from SQL command, which is the SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). if you are not familiar with reporting services, you can follow one of these links:

- [Create data driven PDF on the fly by using SQL server reporting service (SSRS)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19236/Create-data-driven-PDF-on-the-fly-by-using-SQL-ser)
- [Creating a PDF from a Stored Procedure](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/creatingapdffromastoredprocedure/1104/)

## Workaround

You can export data to excel destination, then use a script task to convert the excel  into pdf.

- [Saving Workbooks to PDF and XPS Formats in Excel 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Create Excel file and save as PDF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874412/create-excel-file-and-save-as-pdf)
- [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Method (XlFixedFormatType, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat.aspx)